# 413 Request entity too large when sending request to CloudBees

Tags: post, cloudbees, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a 500 MB file through an HTML form. The web site is hosted on CloudBees RUN@Cloud.

I get a 413 (Request entity too large) error in the access log of the instance:

```
188.180.79.66 - - [18/Jan/2013:08:33:59 +0000] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 413 600 "http://website.net/uploadsite/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"
```

How do I configure the maximum upload size for a CloudBees instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is generally a way to make that reliable.

you can set proxyBuffering=false for your app config - that should help it cope with larger uploads (we use that for app deployments)

but 500MB via a web form seems the wrong technology - you want to have something that can do resumable uploads for files of that size and up.